# Spotfire Prompt Dialog Box Modification

Tags: spotfire

I have a requirement where the wordings displayed in Prompt should be altered to display what we set.

Usually the prompt displays the name of the column along with some text. I want to know if there is any way possible to do it.

[image: Spotfire Webplayer Prompt]

Comment: Prompt for data on demand?

Comment: no. the prompt when we open the report and that too in the Webpayer, adding screenshot for reference

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not aware of a way to change that--perhaps someone else is.